# How to install Canon LBP2900 / 2900B printer on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, scripts, printing, canon

I'm struggling to find out how to install a Canon LBP2900 / 2900B  printer on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Script](https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer) for installing the Linux CAPT Printer Driver for Canon LBP printers on Ubuntu:

```
wget https://github.com/hieplpvip/canon_printer/raw/master/canon_lbp_setup.sh
chmod +x canon_lbp_setup.sh
./canon_lbp_setup.sh
```

After installation there will be a shortcut on your desktop. Run it to check your printer status (if it shows "Ready to Print", the printer is ready to use).